# Currency list update the value of my option using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

function AllCurrency() {
  const [currencies, setCurrencies] = useState([])
  const [base, setBase] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCurrencies(base)
  }, [base])

  const fetchCurrencies = async base => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://api.frankfurter.app/latest?from=${base}`
      )
      const data = await response.json()
      console.log(data)
      const currenciesData = Object.keys(data.rates).map(acc => ({
        rate: data.rates[acc],
        name: acc,
      }))
      setCurrencies(currenciesData)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  const handleBaseChange = e => {
    setBase(e.target.value)
    fetchCurrencies(e.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="all-currency">
        <select value={base} onChange={handleBaseChange}>
          {currencies.length > 0 &&
            currencies.map(currency => (
              <option value={currency.name} key={currency.name}>
                {currency.name}
              </option>
            ))}
        </select>
        <ul>
          {currencies.map(currency => (
            <li key={currency.name}>
              {currency.name} - {currency.rate}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

export default AllCurrency
```

So I wanted to display all the currencies and their value. The default currency is EUR, and when I update my option to a different currency, all the currency value on the list updates with the new base currency value. But my problem is that my option value is not changing/updating to the one im selecting. It is stuck on AUD. But when I console log, it shows that it did update.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an `option element` outside of your map.

```
<React.Fragment>
    <div className="all-currency">
        <select onChange={handleBaseChange}>
            <option key={base}>{base}</option>
            {currencies.length > 0 &&
                currencies.map(currency => (
                    <option key={currency.name} value={currency.name}>
                        {currency.name}
                    </option>
                ))}
        </select>
        <ul>
            {currencies.map(currency => (
                <li key={currency.name}>
                    {currency.name} - {currency.rate}
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    </div>
</React.Fragment>
```

And set the default value to EUR in your useState

```
const [base, setBase] = useState('EUR')
```

Also you can remove `fetchCurrencies` function call from `handleBaseChange`

Because when you change your `base` variable from `useState`, the component will re-render and it will going to call `fetchCurrencies` inside of `useEffect`